# libclang: how to get non-type template arguments from a CXType?

Tags: libclang

Given the following code to parse:

```cpp
template <typename T, int N=3>
class Base {};

using BaseFloat1 = Base<float, 1>;
```

I can get the `TypeAliasDecl` from the last line, get the CXType from that, and the use `clang_Type_getNumTemplateArguments()` to see that there are two template arguments there, but the only option for retrieving the arguments is `clang_Type_getTemplateArgumentAsType()`, which obviously fails for the second, `IntegerLiteral` argument.

Is there any way to get the non-type template argument directly, other than inspecting the children of the `TypeAliasDecl` cursor?